# Selecting previous label element JQUERY

Tags: jquery

So I have a form;

```
<label for="name">Job Date</label><br /><input id="name" class="required" title="Enter a name!" name="name" type="text" />
```

and some Jquery to cycle through each input with class "required" and see if it is empty/blank and if so give this input a red border color, and also the label assosciated with it a red color;

```
function checkreview()
    {   
        var errors = "";
        $(".required").each(function (i) 
        {
            if($(this).val() == "")
            {
                errors += $(this).attr('title')+'<br />';
                $(this).css('border-color','#FF0000');
                //need to select previous label and set color to red                
            }

        });


}
```

So I need a selector that will select the previous label and allow me to give it .css('color','FF0000').

Any ideas how to select the previous label in JQUERY?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about selecting the corresponding label using the id of the input field. So you'll find the label wherever it is.

Replace your comment with this:

```
$('label[for="'+ $(this).attr('id') +'"]').css('color','#FF0000');
```

Comment: this is what I originally thought, however this doesn't work and I really really think it should so I'm going to look deeper to see its not something else blocking it.

Comment: It works for me. Maybe something else is wrong? Does `$('label[for="name"]')` work for you?

Comment: I mean, what does `$('label[for="name"]')` return?

Comment: OK problem solved, the issue was I was missing the # from the color hex code!!

Answer (score 2):

did you try this:

```
$("input").prev("label").css('color','FF0000')
```

Comment: yep I've tried using;

$(this).prev("label").css('color','FF0000')

no joy, thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is a `<br />` element before the input element you can't use `prev()`.

What about

```
$("input").prevAll("label").css('color','FF0000');
```

or you can select the label element with the attribute for

```
$("input").prevAll("label[for=" + $("input").attr ( 'id' ) + "]").css('color','FF0000');
```

[prevAll](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prevAll#expr): Find all sibling elements in front of the current element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).prev().prev().css('color','FF0000');
```

But I would use a css class instead of applying style with jQuery:

```
<style>
div.form label {display:block;}
label.error {color:FF0000}
input.error {border-color:FF0000}
</style>

<div class="form">
<label for="name">Job Date</label>
<input id="name" class="required" title="Enter a name!" name="name" type="text" />
</div>
```

The the validation would change to:

```
function checkreview()
{   
        var errors = "";
        $(".required").each(function (i) 
        {
                if($(this).val() == "")
                {
                        errors += $(this).attr('title')+'<br />';
                        $(this).addClass("error");
                        $(this).prev().addClass("error");    
                }

        });
}
```

Comment: I tried prev().prev() but still no joy, the input box border definately changes though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('label[for='+ $(this).attr('id') +']').css('border','#ff0000 1px solid');
```

or add the label border style to the CSS because you can't see the border color unless you have the border type set... the label[for=*ID*] does work as previously answered.